# splash screen with react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, splash-screen

I'm trying to make a splash screen at the first login to my project with React.js, my codes work properly, but then when I switch between pages, the splash screen works again. when the first project is opened only the splash screen should work, then it shouldn't. Here are my code snippets,
App.js:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar.js";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';
import './App.css';
import Home from "./Menu/Home.js";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer.js";
import About from "./Menu/About.js";
import Contact from "./Menu/Contact/Contact.js";

function App() {
  const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSplash(false);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showSplash ? (
        <SplashScreen />
      ) : (
        <div className="app__body">
          <Navbar />
          <Home />
          <About />
          <Contact />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`
```

SplashScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SplashScreen.css';

const SplashScreen = () => {
  return (
    <div className="splash-screen">
      <h1>Welcome to My App</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

Comment: Save that information in localstorage

Comment: useEffect(() => {
      const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        setShowSplash(true);
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
        setTimeout(() => {
          SetShowSplash(false);
        }, 2000); 
      }
    }, []); I updated the useEffect section like this, the splash screen didn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior might be occurring because every time you navigate between pages, the entire `App` component is probably being re-rendered, which resets the `showSplash` state back to `true`. This would make the splash screen appear again.

You need to store the state of the splash screen somewhere where it will persist between component re-renders. You could use `localStorage` to keep track of whether the splash screen has been displayed.

Here is an example:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar.js";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';
import './App.css';
import Home from "./Menu/Home.js";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer.js";
import About from "./Menu/About.js";
import Contact from "./Menu/Contact/Contact.js";

function App() {
  const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(localStorage.getItem('splashShown') !== 'true');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (showSplash) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowSplash(false);
        localStorage.setItem('splashShown', 'true');
      }, 2000);
  
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [showSplash]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showSplash ? (
        <SplashScreen />
      ) : (
        <div className="app__body">
          <Navbar />
          <Home />
          <About />
          <Contact />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this updated version, when the app loads, it checks `localStorage` for a value under the key 'splashShown'. If it finds a value of `'true'`, it knows that the splash screen has already been shown, so it sets `showSplash` to `false`. Otherwise, it defaults to `true` and the splash screen is shown.

When the splash screen is shown, it sets a timer to hide the splash screen after 2 seconds. At the same time, it stores the value `'true'` under the 'splashShown' key in `localStorage`.

With this approach, even if the `App` component is re-rendered, the splash screen will only be shown the first time the user visits the app (or if they clear their local storage).

Keep in mind that using `localStorage` can have implications for the privacy of your users, so make sure you are complying with any relevant regulations and user expectations.